# Manipulação de Imagens - Condição da forma " image[ CONDIÇÃO ] "

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando com manipulação de imagens em Python.

Me deparei com uma linha de código do tipo:

```
image[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]
```

Sendo "image" e "dst" imagens.

O que se encontra dentro dos colchetes "[]", indexando "image" é uma condição para o *pixel* dessa imagem? A atribuição será efetivada quando a condição for verdadeira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um pouco difícil responder sua pergunta sem contexto. Entretanto, eu suponho que essas imagens estejam armazenadas como vetores e matrizes numéricas.

Se minha suposição estiver correta, isso se chama "indexamento lógico", semelhante ao que é oferecido pelo numpy (se não for exatamente a mesma coisa).

Vou explicar através de um exemplo usando numpy. Começamos criando um vetor:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x = np.array(l)
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

O vetor e a lista se comportam bem diferentemente. É digno de nota o seguinte:

```
>>> l>2
True
>>> x>2
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Quando você faz uma comparação entre um vetor e um número, o resultado é um vetor lógico com o valor da comparação para cada elemento do vetor. Isso é verdade para comparações mais complexas também:

```
>>> l%2==0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
>>> x%2==0
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

E quando você usa um vetor lógico no lugar do índice de outro vetor, o resultado é um vetor com todos os elementos correspondentes a posições ocupadas por "True" no vetor lógico:

```
>>> x[x>2]
array([3, 4])
>>> x[x%2==0]
array([2, 4])
```

Finalmente, quando você faz uma atribuição, essa se aplica aos elementos do vetor original:

```
>>> x[x%2==0] *= 10
>>> x
array([ 1, 20,  3, 40])
```

Você pode atribuir uma lista, e os valores da lista são repassados em ordem:

```
>>> x[x%2==1] = [-1,-3]
>>> x
array([-1, 20, -3, 40])
```

Mas a lista precisa ser do tamanho certo. Ou seja, se tem `n` valores que satisfazem a condição e você passa uma lista, a lista precisa ter exatamente `n` valores:

```
>>> x[x%2==1] = [-1,-3, -5]
>>> x[x%2==0] = range(10, 150, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 2 output values where the mask is true
>>> x = np.array(range(15))
>>> x[x%2==0] = [-1,-3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 2 input values to the 8 output values where the mask is true
```

---

O que o seu trecho de código faz é equivalente a isso. Botando em palavras: as posições do vetor `image` correspondentes às posições do vetor `dst` em que o valor é maior que 1% do máximo deste vetor recebem os valores [0,0,255].

Como isso parece um trio de valores RGB, imagino que o que esteja acontecendo não seja exatamente igual a atribuir uma lista a um vetor. Mais provável que os pixels de `dst` que satisfazem a condição corresponderão a pixeis azuis em `image`.